# Can't get Texting component of MIT app inventor to work

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the texting component of the MIT App Inventor 2 to work.

I am using a texting component and one block that looks like:

when textmessage.MessageReceived do
    call TextToSpeech1.Speak message get messageText

When I receive a text message, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Could I see your blocks real quick?
I have made a texting application that works but requires money to text.
This could be your problem if you don't want to use the application to text.

Comment: Since I'm new here, I couldn't upload a picture, otherwise I would have included the blocks. Is there an easy way for me to communicate this information to you?

Answer (score 0):

The App you build has to be running, visible in the screen, on a real device - at the time you receive the sms; otherwise you could at least be notified of the reception if the 'ReceivingEnabled' properties is set to 'always' or to '3'.