# How to record number and text message using texting component?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm coding an app with Mit App Inventor2, which is expected to record number and text message of received sms using the `Texting` component but I can't figure out how to access to number and text of a sms received when the app isn't visible.

With `ReceivingEnabled` properties set to `always` in the panel, the app can only:

- receive number and text if it is running visible in the screen during the reception of the sms (and correctly past them to other variables);
- notify the reception of a sms if the app is closed but I think running in the background (anyway not visible between the opened app);
- correctly do nothing if I stop it from the application setting of the phone.

I tried this actions by texting myself with the built apk installed in the phone.

I searched and found [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962761/cant-get-texting-component-of-mit-app-inventor-to-work/58266230#58266230) asking quite the same thing, and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965603/mit-app-inventor-2-may-i-how-to-place-alarms-in-the-android-notification-area/36968726#36968726) where Taifun states that "This feature however is available only in the United States."

Here there is [the block I should improve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdGF3.png).

[The same question posted in mitappinventor google group.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mitappinventortest/YYzUyMg0po8)

Comment: you might get more answers if you ask in the MIT App Inventor forum at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to search help in it.